# Regression Manhwa/Webtoon where the main female lead died due to illness

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, manga

I read this manhwa a year ago but I forgot the title. I changed phones so most of the titles are lost and since the site where i use to read was brought down.

So I vaguely remember about the story is that the female lead is on her death bed. She had a miserable life with her husband, I think a duke or something,  always away to wars to earn money and her son also leaving her. Their son was brainwashed by the husband's mistress (the husband's ex-lover I think?) that he was abandoned by the sick wife.

After the death of the female lead, her son with blonde hair(?) became an archmage and went to the enemy camp after finding out what his father did and all of those were lies about her stepmother and real mother and that his father regretted every single day since the death of the female lead which then resulted to the regression of the female lead, she didn't know though that her husband also have memories of their previous life.

I hope this is really an independent webtoon/manhwa and not a mix up made by my memory.

Answer (score 3):

Is this ***[Duchess in the Glass House](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/j2vmrnt/duchess-in-the-glass-house)***...?

> Rayna Vinosht was always known as the cursed one. Unloved by her father, she’s married off to the handsome Duke Edgar Heathvilian, but he soon becomes cold to her, taking away her son, and giving him to the seductive Monica Espert. But Rayna has a second chance at life thanks to Ondine, an adorable water spirit, who forms a contract with her. Soon Rayna has supernatural powers and the confidence to rule over her estate like a strong duchess, but what will happen now that Edgar is falling in love with her?

From what I've read so far, this seems to match most of the details, at least.

- The protagonist, Raina Vinosht, is the daughter of a duke who marries Edgar Heathville, the son of another duke.
- Unbeknownst to Rayna, Edgar was ordered by her father not to show her any love.
- Raina gives birth to one blond son, Elle, who is taken away from her at a young age and turned against her.
- Edgar has an ex-fiancée, Monica Esbert, who is still in the picture, and resents Raina for having taken her place in her eyes.
- When Raina is lying on her deathbed, Elle is portrayed as being more attached to Monica than he is to her.
- Edgar leaves his wife and son to go off to war at times.
- 15 years after Raina's death, Elle has grown up to become a spiritualist (having inherited those powers from his mother), and angrily confronts his father about the way his mother was treated.
- Raina and Edgar both regress into their younger selves, and remember their previous life together, although they don't tell one another about this.